# Why i cannot do log in?

Tags: java

The loop is malfuctioning.

I have tried replacing "contains" with "equals"

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);   
        User cg = new User("Clarke ","griffinc@gmail.com");
        User bb = new User("Bellamy ","blakeb@gmail.com");
        User ob = new User("Octavia ","blakeo@gmail.com");
        User rr = new User("Raven","reyesr@gmail.com");
        User jm = new User("John","murphyj@gmail.com");
        User mg = new User("Monty","greenm@gmail.com");

        ArrayList <User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(cg);
        users.add(bb);
        users.add(ob);
        users.add(rr);
        users.add(jm);
        users.add(mg);

        //login
        boolean login = false;
        User loginUser = new User(" "," ");
        while (login == false) {
            for (int j = 0; j < users.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(j+1 +":"+ users.get(j).getUsername());
            }
            System.out.println("Give your username:");  
            String username = scan.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                if (username.contains(users.get(i).getUsername())) {
                    loginUser = users.get(i);
                    login = true;
                } else {
                    login = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

It won't log in even if I put the aforementioned usernames as an answer. It was supposed to accept those usernames as correct answers and stop the loop. However everything seems to be considered as a wrong answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `username.equals` instead of `username.contains`?

Comment: Don't set `login` to `false` or it'll only exit if the last one matches.

Comment: You should stop setting `login` to `false` in the `for-loop`, otherwise, unless you select `Monty`, you won't be able to login EVER.  In fact you could use `break;` to break out of the loop when you set `login` to `true`, but that might be a bit more advanced then it needs to be

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts. Once you've posted them, they're licensed to the community and they're kept here because they might help other people in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is in your `if-else` statement of the you `for-loop`

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    if (username.contains(users.get(i).getUsername())) {
        loginUser = users.get(i);
        login = true;
    } else {
        login = false;
    }
}
```

Here, unless you enter `Monty`, `login` will always be `false`, as it's reset when ever the name doesn't match.  Better to set it outside the loop and only change it when you need to, for example...

```
login = false;
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    if (username.contains(users.get(i).getUsername())) {
        loginUser = users.get(i);
        login = true;
    }
}
```

Also, beware, you have spaces at the end of some of your user names...

```
User cg = new User("Clarke ","griffinc@gmail.com");
//                        ^--- This will screw with you
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is in your if-else statement i just added a break statement since when you find a matching name you continue your loop and if the next name is not matching you are setting the value of login to false while you need to stop the loop immediately when you find your match adding to that you should change contains to equals method since if you type for example "jo" you can login as "john" when using contains

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
     Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);   
     User cg = new User("Clarke ","griffinc@gmail.com");
     User bb = new User("Bellamy ","blakeb@gmail.com");
     User ob = new User("Octavia ","blakeo@gmail.com");
     User rr = new User("Raven","reyesr@gmail.com");
     User jm = new User("John","murphyj@gmail.com");
     User mg = new User("Monty","greenm@gmail.com");

     ArrayList <User> users= new ArrayList<User>();
     users.add(cg);
     users.add(bb);
     users.add(ob);
     users.add(rr);
     users.add(jm);
     users.add(mg);


     //login
     boolean login=false;
     User loginUser=new User(" "," ");

         while (login==false)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<users.size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.println(j+1 +":"+ users.get(j).getUserName());
            }
            System.out.println("Give your username:");  
            String username=scan.next();
            for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
            {
                if(username.equals(users.get(i).getUserName() ) ) 
                {
                    loginUser=users.get(i);
                    login=true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    login=false;
                }
           }
```